# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Estou utilizando o jquery validate e estava funcionando normalmente, agora está me retornando o seguinte erro, já verifiquei as referencias, mudei, porém continua com o mesmo problema:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mobile/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/mobile/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style2.css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/iconepagina.ico">
<script src="/javascript/validacao.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mobile/validacao.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js"></script>
```

E aqui é o meu validacao.js

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#contact-form').validate({
    rules: {
      txtNome: {
        minlength: 2,
        required: true
      }
    },
    highlight: function(element) {
      $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
    },
    success: function(element) {
      element.text('OK!').addClass('valid')
        .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
    }
  });

});
```

Toda forma que referencio, permanece o mesmo erro.

Segue como está o erro console:

> jquery_master.min.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument. (validacao.js:44)
>       at j (jquery_master.min.js:3)
>       at k (jquery_master.min.js:3)

E aqui é como está as referências agora:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mobile/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/mobile/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style2.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/iconepagina.ico">
    <script src="/javascript/jquery_master.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mobile/validacao.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/additional-methods.js"></script>
    
    <script src="/javascript/validacao.js"></script>
```

Todas alterações que faço, nenhuma volta a funcionar o validate.

Answer (score 0):

Há alguma falha no caminho definido para o arquivo `.js` do `jQuery`, por isso está sendo apresentado esse erro, talvez o caminho para o arquivo foi colocado de forma incompleta e o navegador não está conseguindo encontrar o arquivo.

Se adicionar uma importação externa do arquivo `jquery.min.js` como fiz na primeira linha do código abaixo, o erro não é mais apresentado:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#contact-form').validate({
    rules: {
      txtNome: {
        minlength: 2,
        required: true
      }
    },
    highlight: function(element) {
      $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
    },
    success: function(element) {
      element.text('OK!').addClass('valid')
        .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mobile/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/mobile/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style2.css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/iconepagina.ico">
<script src="/javascript/validacao.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mobile/validacao.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js"></script>
```

Comment: Na verdade o erro ainda persiste, informa o mesmo problema, mesmo adicionando a linha que você informou.

Comment: @marianac_costa Você colocou a linha em questão antes de tudo e dentro da `tag head` da sua página?

Comment: Coloquei sim, igual você me auxiliou, porem o mesmo problema continua.

Comment: Experimenta tirar todas as referencias pra arquivos .js ou .css, deixa apenas a referencia pro jquery e pro validate, vê se o problema persiste após isso.

Comment: Ainda persiste @LeandroLima, estava funcionando perfeitamente, creio que o problema está mesmo na referencia, porém não consigo voltar fazendo funcionar.